# Excel VBA loop rows until empty then paste into empty cell

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm trying to paste a range from Word into Excel.
The macro loops through every Word doc in the directory. Each time it selects a range I'd like it to paste into cell H10, but if cell H10 is not empty I would like it to move down to cell H11 and so on.

My code works if I do this:

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim oDoc As Document
Dim oExcel As Object, oWB As Object, ObjWorksheet As Object

...

oDoc.Range(rng1.End, rng2.Start).Select
    ' select from the end of range 1 to the start of range 2 (after name but before keywords)
    Selection.Copy
    ' copy the selection

    ObjWorksheet.Range("H10").Select
    If IsEmpty(ObjWorksheet.Range("H10")) = True Then
    ObjWorksheet.Paste
    Else: ObjWorksheet.Range("H10").Offset(1, 0).Select
        If IsEmpty(ObjWorksheet.Range("H10").Offset(1, 0)) = True Then
        ObjWorksheet.Paste
            Else: ObjWorksheet.Range("H10").Offset(2, 0).Select
                If IsEmpty(ObjWorksheet.Range("H10").Offset(2, 0)) = True Then
                ObjWorksheet.Paste
                    Else: ObjWorksheet.Range("H10").Offset(3, 0).Select
                        If IsEmpty(ObjWorksheet.Range("H10").Offset(3, 0)) = True Then
                        ObjWorksheet.Paste
                            Else: ObjWorksheet.Range("H10").Offset(4, 0).Select
                                If IsEmpty(ObjWorksheet.Range("H10").Offset(4, 0)) = True Then
                                ObjWorksheet.Paste
                                    Else: ObjWorksheet.Paste
                                End If
                        End If
                End If
        End If
    End If
```

But how can I refine it so it offsets one cell down each time automatically?

Comment: Try `Do Until ActiveCell.Value = ""` instead

Comment: Thanks, I'm still getting the same issue though. It runs perfectly first time and then pastes on top of eachother the second time.

Answer (score 0):

The condition is set wrongly try this

```
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)=False
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

ObjWorksheet.Paste
```

The line

```
  Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)=False
```

Will select the next cell below one row active cell until it isn't empty

Comment: Thanks, I actually want the cell that I'm pasting into to be empty so I tried

    Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)=True
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    Loop

    ObjWorksheet.Paste

But it's still working the first time I run it then pasting one on top of the other the second time I run it.

Comment: Why did you set it to True set it to False.

Comment: Because that will select the cell below one row active cell until it ISN'T empty. I want to select the cell below one row active cell when it IS empty.

Answer (score 0):

I think ths script below would be MUCh easier to wrk with if you want to import data from tables in multiple Word files.

```
Sub WordToExcel()
Dim wdApp As Word.Application
Dim wdDoc As Word.Document
Dim x As Integer
Dim strFilename As String
Dim strFolder As String
Dim temp As String

Set wdApp = New Word.Application
'initialise counter
x = 1
'search for first file in directory
strFolder = "C:\Test\"
strFilename = Dir(strFolder & "*.doc")
'amemd folder name
Do While strFilename <> ""
Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(strFolder & strFilename)
temp = wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 1).Range.Text 'read word cell
Range("A2").Offset(x, 0) = temp
temp = wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 2).Range.Text 'read word cell
Range("A2").Offset(x, 1) = temp
'etc
temp = wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 3).Range.Text 'read word cell
Range("A2").Offset(x, 2) = temp
temp = wdDoc.Tables(1).Cell(2, 4).Range.Text 'read word cell
Range("A2").Offset(x, 3) = temp

wdDoc.Close
x = x + 1
strFilename = Dir
Loop
wdApp.Quit
Set wdDoc = Nothing
Set wdApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll try that out.
The reason I am not currently using tables is because each field has multiple paragraphs and a table would make it look cluttered.
Also, the Word docs are going out to/being used by editors and freelancers that are very Excel-averse and adding tables seems like it will just make Word look more like Excel to them. 
What I want to do is extract the text between point A and point B and put it into an Excel cell, multiple times.